# NSMutableArray Count is showing wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I had NSMutableArray of 10 arrays of items. Each array is allocated as

say e.g.;

```
NSArray *myArray=[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsofFile:pListPath];
```

but at 5th array has no data, So the count should be 9, but it is showing 4.

My problem is that i want to get all 9 array items data except 5 th array.

How it is possible.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: show some code and show snapshot of your plist .

Comment: NSString *pathWages=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Wages.plist"];
  
  dataWages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:pathWages];

Comment: edit your question and place code it there and show snapshot of plist file. little bit confustion here..

Comment: It is easy to down vote , but for them it is difficult to answer it

Comment: hey user3045524, I didn't do that. I've asked to explain more.

Comment: plistFile is empty and has no data

Comment: I've asked about `Wages.plist' file. What you have done with that.?

Comment: How are you adding objects to your array and how are you setting the 5th object to be empty? If you want to add an empty object, use NSNull, not nil. 

Also check that you are using an NSMutableArray, rather than an NSArray as NSArray will be terminated by nil, thereby ignoring the following objects.

Comment: @AndyKaminski : I think this is actual answer. If you sure with this answer, post it as answer that will help other visitors.

Comment: @mani Yes, I think that it's the correct answer but didn't want to post it as such without seeing the code that related to the question in case it was something else that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have an array with 10 arrays. If the 5th array has no data then your NSMutableArray will still have 10 items in it. Even if one object is empty, it is still an object. The count of items of your 5th array will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is you try to load from plist file

In plist even if 5th object in the parent array must contain an empty array, which means the plist contains total of 10 rows of array. and read the plist into an array then remove the empty sub-array.